# How can I make a copy of the file that I just uploaded to the server using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I upload a file to the server and save it using FileUpload.SaveAs() method in C#.

When I upload this file, I also want to make a copy of the same file in a different folder so that I can manipulate the copy and save the original one as it is. How can I do that using C#?

So far, I have been able to save the file in a folder called myFolder in the server.

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string path = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                path = path.Replace(" ", "");
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/myFolder/") + path);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `File.Copy()` from `System.IO`.

```
string path = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
path = path.Replace(" ", "");
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/myFolder/") + path); 

string source = Server.MapPath("~/myFolder/") + path;
string destination = Server.MapPath("~/myotherfolder/") + path;
File.Copy(source, destination);
```

[`File.Copy`](http://%20%20File.Copy(source,%20destination);) has an overload if you want to overwrite an existing file with the same name:

```
File.Copy(source, destination, true); // overwrite existing file.
```